# Is there a way where I can view which files were replaced when I do a Get Latest in TFS?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tfs

When I do a get latest with TFS, is there a setting or something that will show a display window showing all of the new files that are being replaced when I do a get latest?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at the output window, there should be a selection called 'Source Control - Team Foundation' in 'Show output from' drop down. That should show you which files are replaced as a result of get latest.

Comment: What toolbar is the 'shot output from' drop down in?

Comment: 'Show output from' drop down is on the toolbar of the output window. You can bring the output window by View>Output or Ctrl+Alt+O unless you changed the keyboard bindings in VS.

Comment: Any idea how can we write the output to a file with warning/conflicts? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4552352/tfs-get-latest/8006460#8006460