# TFS + get latest

Tags: tfs

When I get the latest version from TFS, is there a way to list the files that were updated?

Comment: What are you using to Get Latest? Command line? Source Control Explorer in Visual Studio? Directly from a context menu in Visual Studio or Windows Explorer?

Answer (score 6):

if you are using the Visual Studio IDE, you can see the list of files get in the "Output" window.
To see the "Output" window, select menu View-->Output.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Note that you may have to click on the drop-down list at the top of the output window and select "Source Control" to display the output form the source control system (rather than build or debug output).

Comment: @Jason Williams, I can't believe I've overlooked that for so long. Thanks man!!

Answer (score 1):

To your question tf.exe get may help http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx7sdeyf.aspx.
So,

> tf get c:\MyWorkspace /all /recursive /noprompt >C:\TFResults\results.txt

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

1. Open Team Explorer
2. Select project
3. Double click Source Control
4. Optional to get latest: Right click the folder you need and choose Get Latest Version or Get Specific Version and then choose Latest and Overwrite.
5. Right click the folder you need and choose View History.

Comment: This shows you the history of changes to the files, but will not show you which files were updated in the local workspace by the Get.

Answer (score 0):

You need to take a look into the files on the Output Window. The changeset list, can give you an idea of which are the latest changes files and you can search for those changes. 
But a dummy idea is to map your tfs workspace to another folder and download all the files, then user the WinMerge, BeyondCompare or another tool to compare the files in the specific folders you have to get the differences between the latest code, and your current one. 
Hope this help